# "redis-benchmark" command is not working for hscan or hget

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, redis, benchmarking

when i run

```
redis-benchmark -t hscan -r 1000000 -p 6379 -h 127.0.0.1
```

I dont get any output

but when i run

```
redis-benchmark -t get -r 1000000 -p 6379 -h 127.0.0.1
```

I get output like this

```
====== GET ======
  100000 requests completed in 1.84 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1
  host configuration "save": 3600 1 300 100 60 10000
  host configuration "appendonly": no
  multi-thread: no

0.00% <= 0.1 milliseconds
```

Why benchmarking is notworking for hscan or hget.
How can I benchmark these commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***`-t`*** doesn't works with SCAN and HSCAN for some reason.

this works -->

```
redis-benchmark hscan -r 1000000 -p 6379 -h 127.0.0.1
```